# creating jquery plugin - does not work when used on the same element twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been using prototypeJS until now, so forgive me for this nooby jquery question :P

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/wAcVs/

The plugin is being applied to #cont1 on load. #cont2 has not been touched so far. When you click on the buttons at the top, you can see that its working for #cont2, but not for #cont1.

I can see the arguments from

```
$('#cont1').myPlugin({id:'321', width:'200', height:'100'})
```

are taking effect on my options variable, but from then on "this" is empty, and the element is not changing at all.

How can i get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work twice because you're changing the ID to something else, so when using `$("#cont1")` for example, there's nothing to find.  If you just remove the `.attr('id', 'plugin_'+options.id)`, you'll see it working.

[You can test it with the changes here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wAcVs/1/), note that I changed the `.changed` selector, since when the id remains, the `#cont1` and `#cont2` CSS selectors are more specific than just `.changed`.

Comment: haha, of course... an earlier version of this plugin didnt work on multiple elements, so i made some changes and forgot to remove the assignmet of the id, thats all.